# What axiom in Math says "similar inputs should yield similar outputs"?

Tags: terminology, axioms

It is easy to take for granted the simple idea that similar input $x$ to a function $f(x)$ should yield similar outputs - such that if the difference between $x$ is arbitrary small, then we should also be able to get arbitrary small changes in $f(x)$.

But what is this fundamental property called? Is it just *function continuity*? But even *continuity* seems to rely on this fact. What stops me from arguing that only arbitrary far-apart numbers as inputs will yield similar outputs?

It feels like there should exist an even more fundamental axiom upon which all this is based. What is this axiom called?

Comment: First you need to make clear what 'similar' might mean. Dependending on that you may arrive at different concepts, like, as you mentioned, continuity. Another one would be symmetry. There are no axioms behind these, these are just definitions.

Comment: In essence, you want to express the idea that $x\approx y$ implies $f(x)\approx f(y)$? There are many functions that do not satisfy it, so it can't be an axiom. (By the way, I believe there are _two_ ways of making the statement of that "axiom" rigorous; one is the definition of a continuous function, the other is the definition of a uniformly continuous function.)

Comment: Does $x^2$ satisfy the property you want? We have that $100^2=10000$, but $100.01^2=10002.0001$. The inputs are $0.01$ units away from each other, but the outputs are more than $2$ units away from each other. So it's a bit unclear whether or not $x^2$ satisfies your property. Formally, $x^2$ is _continuous_, but not _uniformly continuous_.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger can you elaborate yourself? I do not understand the point you are trying to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an *axiom*, it's exactly what the property "continuity" *means*. And there are functions which aren't continuous: for an extreme example, take Conway's base 13 function $h$, which has the property that for every $x$ and $y$, and for every $\delta>0$, there is some $c\in (x-\delta, x+\delta)$ such that $h(c)=y$. That is, it's completely uncontrollable.

---

Regarding axioms: There are certain (extremely rare) contexts where it can make sense to work in a system one of whose axioms is "*every* function is continuous." Separately, one might argue that "every function *occuring in nature* is continuous," but that is imprecise. In general, though, if you're looking for an axiom that tells you that you can take continuity for granted, there isn't one - because you can't!

Comment: So 'similar' means 'close together'? in which sense?

Comment: @Thomas The second half of the OP's first sentence strongly indicates that they mean closeness in the usual sense - small distance.

Comment: So there is no underlying axiom and I'm just getting wound up in the definition nomenclature of "continuity" then?

Comment: @Alan What do you think that "underlying axiom" would say? Is there some statement about functions and continuity you think needs to be made, that doesn't already follow from the usual axioms for functions and from the definition of continuity? (I am genuinely not sure what you are asking; if you can explain what you think this underlying axiom should do/say, I can answer your question better.)

Comment: I think you're right and its continuity. Im trying to think up of a statement that does not follow by the definition alone, and I cant